# Operadriver not functioning

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Seleniumwebdriver and Maven and trying to run a simple test on Opera .
I have added a dependency for opera driver ,version 1.5 in my pom file.

Additionally my selenium-server dependency is 2.39.0.I have tried downgrading both the dependencies,but still my opera driver isn't working which shows the below error.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.
Error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Keyboard at com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver.browsers.OperaDriverTestCase.testBasicOperaUsage(OperaDriverTestCase.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at  com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Keyboard
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 27 more
```

my code is as below:
    package com.seleniumsimplified.webdriver.browsers;

```
import com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver;
import com.opera.core.systems.OperaProfile;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class OperaDriverTestCase {


@Test
public void testBasicOperaUsage(){

    WebDriver operaDriver = new OperaDriver();
    operaDriver.get("http://sadfasd.com");

    assertThat(operaDriver.getTitle(),is(""));
    operaDriver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: Could I get your Operating System?

Answer (score 0):

Jagori,

Please look at this [link](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/selenium-users/13b3h0h9pp/hasinputdevices-not-working-for-selenium-java-2-37-0) where Simon Stewart explains that the HasInputDevice import has moved into a different package. The HasImportDevice import is where the Class Definition for the Keyboard lives.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi Curtis,Thanks for your reply.But,my code doesn't have any userinteractions kind of stuff in it.I have just edited my original question and inserted the code and full error message.My Opera driver is just not responding.I can run my test on firefox,chrome but not on Opera.

Comment: @Jagori The error given above is way different than the original error posted. I'll see what I can figure out. If you could get me your Operating System that would super helpful as well.

Comment: Yes its windows 7.Am sorry about that as I wasn't able to cut paste my code initially which was to be in code format.